# How to input to a batch file and read it?

Tags: batch-file

I want something similar to `printf` & `scanf` in C in batch scripting?

This is my script

```
for /F "delims=;" %%i in (servers11.txt) do  (
type \\triss-s02-vm\ITG\Triton\GroupConfig.csv | grep -i %%i > temp13.txt

REM type temp.txt | gawk -F"," '{print $1}'
)
```

Here I am creating `servers11.txt` manually and entering value there. I want to enter it from command prompt. Please help me in doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SET /P to ask for user input :

```
set /P SERV=SERVERNAME?
echo %SERV% >> temp13.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a file from scratch on the command line, use `copy con`:

```
C:\>copy con servers11.txt
serverA
serverB
^Z
C:\>type servers11.txt
serverA
serverB
C:\>_
```

You end `copy con` by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> (the `^Z` above).

Comment: @echo off
set /p servers11.txt=Server name: 

for /F "delims=;" %%i in (servers11.txt) do  (
type \\triss-s02-vm\ITG\Triton\GroupConfig.csv | grep -i %%i > temp13.txt

)  This code is not working.. Error :- servers11.txt not found

Comment: How exactly is that related to my answer?